# document.getElementById(..) gives null even though element is present

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following program in which a user can enter any name in a search box after which I redirect the user to a page called usernameSearchResults.php where I print a list of the usernames obtained in the form of an array from usernamesearch.php. Here is the javascript:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
$(".searchBarForm").submit(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var search=document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0].value;     

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'usernamesearch.php',
        data: 
        {
            search:search
        },
        success: function (response) 
        { 
            window.location.href="usernameSearchResults.php";
            response = JSON.parse(response);

            var array_length = Object.keys(response).length;//getting array length          

            for(var i=0;i<array_length;i++){

                if(i==0){
                    document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML="<a href=userprofile.php?id="+response[0].id+">"+response[0].username+"</a><br>";//i=0
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML+="<a href=userprofile.php?id="+response[i].id+">"+response[i].username+"</a><br>";
                }

            }

            window.stop();//stops page from refreshing any further(put here to fix a bug that was occuring)
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }              
    });

return false;
})
});
```

This is usernameSearchResults.php(inside  tags):

```
<h1>Username Search Results</h1>

<p id="searchResults"></p>
```

But the problem is that whenever I go to any other page say index.php and enter the username to be searched, the page redirected to is indeed usernameSearchResults.php but the page is blank and error in the console shown says document.getElementById("searchResults") is null.But if I stay at the page usernameSearchResults.php and refresh it and then search any name again, then the results are correctly obtained. What is the problem here?

Comment: Why do you use `document.getElementById()` and jQuery at the same time?

Comment: Actually, I find this easier to understand

Comment: You shouldn't mix jQuery and vanilla JS. Why force the user to download the jQuery file and then not even use it? Also, there can be confusion when you have jQuery objects and JS objects or DOM elements in one file of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the user is being redirected to usernameSearchResults.php but the JavaScript code is still being executed from the current page, which have no element with id "searchResults" defined.

As @Kashkain said, one way to achieve what you want is to pass your response variable in your redirection url and process it then into your other page.

Comment: ohh,,So how should I fix this?

Comment: @KlaraNewbie Pass variable on your url, add js script on your redirected page and do your treatment if you get the variable from the ajax success redirect

Comment: This should be added to the answer.

Comment: I understand what youre saying guys but is it safe and efficient to pass an entire array in the url?

Comment: @Aigloun so I tried to do what you said but my url on passing an array through it shows [object][Object].... how do I get rid of this? Is there a way to pass the array through POST?

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying. Yes you can pass any variable through post, just like you did for your search data

Comment: But how can I pass the array in the response to usernameSearchResults.php from the Ajax success function?

Comment: @Aigloun What I meant by this comment `"so I tried to do what you said but my url on passing an array through it shows [object][Object].... how do I get rid of this?"` was that I tried to send the response variable through a GET request to usernameSearchResults.php but my url looked like this: usernameSearchResults.php?searchquery=[object][Object][object][Object]... So how should I get rid of the "[object][Object].." part?

Comment: For example, You could add a form (POST action = your php) with a hidden input, change the input's value by your array in the success of your ajax call, submit it and process the data in your php

Comment: Dude!!! It finally works!! Thank you soo much man! I dont know how to thank you! I;ve been working on it the whole evening! Wouldn't have been possible without your help! I can now sleep peacefully xD

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the new document could very well still not have been loaded when you call getElementById.
You could add a listener on your target element which would trigger on the load event. In this event's handler you could execute the operations that are now giving you an error.

I have never done or tried this, but maybe something like this would work:

```
$('#searchResults').on('load', function() {
   //execute code here
});
```

Or you could add a form to the page with action="target_url" method="post" and send your response data through post by doing form.submit, and place the problematic code into usernameSearchResults.php, which will need to read data from POST - this way you can send your ajax data to the new page